# Display message to user on ItemCommand event

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, telerik-grid

I have grid in my ASP.NET page (actualy it's Telerik RadGrid). There is `GridButtonColumn`, and `OnItemCommand` event is called when user clicks the link in this cell.

Right now, after user clicks, some data is prepared in the background and sent by e-mail. At the end of my method I want to display to user, that operation was succeeded. Any ideas, how can I reach that goal? I cannot use JavaScript in this event (there is no OnClick event or ClientScript property), and I want user to stay on current page, so also no `Response.Redirect` can be used.

Please, share some ideas, how to inform user, that operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is the best option , To display Alert or Popup to user.
You can also do one thing , Place One DIV on Header of grid and give some style to DIV and display your message on that div.

Comment: And how would I do that? JS is not my strong part. I don't know, how to start client-side script from server-side code behind.

Comment: Wait... this idea with div is actually good! I added div with `runat="server"` and set it's visibility on success.